# javascript appending to an url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append a comma and then var after the `+str` here, unsure of how to proceed.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getopen.php?q="+str,true);
```

My ultimate goal is to pass two inputs to a processing page live in order to check a few things against a database.  I have it working for a single one using GET in the url, just can't seem to figure out how to add an additional item.  My current line of reasoning is getting everything to the processing page, then exploding it in php and creating variables there to use in the query to mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple string concatentation:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getopen.php?q=" + str + "," + variable);
```